# make a see more/see less function?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

so basically I am trying to make it so if the dynamically generated description has over 5 lines it will use line-clamp and only show 5 lines and have a see more/see less thing

```html
<div class="description-container">
  <div class="description">
    <p>{@html data.description}</p>
  </div>
  <span class="showMoreLess">Show More</span>
</div>
```

```css
  .description-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .description {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 70rem;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .description p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

that is my code as of right now I know the solution might be simple but I'm a semi new developer so anything helps

I haven't tried anything cus I'm too dumb lol

Comment: Do a little research: https://fortwin.hashnode.dev/creating-a-read-more-see-less-button-with-css-and-javascript. If you get stuck somewhere, we will help you. But it's useless to give you a full solution.

Comment: If you use `@html`, make sure it is sanitized in case it contains unknown/user input, otherwise that can be dangerous.

Comment: Also if the description can contain any HTML, it is pretty much impossible to always determine the size of 5 lines.

Comment: Is the `data.description` in html?

Answer (score 1):

I put this solution together, and will post it here with this disclaimer:  I did not test it with arbitrary content.  I have only tested it with a paragraph.

Also, this is probably a tricky thing to set up correctly.  Many CSS inherited styling might come into play that can skew the result in one way or another.  This requires thorough testing.

### Solution

Code first.  This can be seen working in this [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/342121ca9c2f4944ae376b77e0f17b0c?version=4.2.1).

```html
<script>
    let hContents, hReference;
    $: exceeds = hContents > hReference;
</script>
<div class="content" bind:clientHeight={hContents}>
    <div class="reference" bind:clientHeight={hReference}>
        {#each { length: 5 } as _, i}
            <span>{i}</span>
        {/each}
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur pulvinar. At lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque.</p>
</div>

{#if exceeds}
    <h2>Exceeds!</h2>
{/if}

<style>
    div.content {
        font-size: 14pt;
        line-height: 1.2;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.reference {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        width: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    div.reference > span {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

#### Explanation

We create a reference DIV as a child of the container we want to measure to hopefully inherit important styles like `font-size` and `line-height`.  We make this child invisible and absolutely-positioned so it doesn't interfere with the document's flow.

We then fill our invisible container with the maximum number of lines we want to test for.

Finally, we use Svelte's dimension-binding feature to measure the height of our reference container and the subject container.  If the height of the subject container exceeds the height of our reference container, the subject container has more lines.